# HTML page embedded Google Docs Viewer / Office Web Apps Viewer for intranet files

Tags: html, embed, google-document-viewer

Google Docs Viewer / Office Web Apps Viewer processes file on Google / Microsoft server. It firstly downloads file to the server and so if file is located within my private protected internal network of my organization which Google / Microsoft has no access to then it will not work.

```
<iframe src='https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=[INTRANET_OFFICE_FILE_URL]' />
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=[INTRANET_OFFICE_FILE_URL]' />
```

Is information above correct?

Are there any viewers which can work with intranet files?

I'm interested in viewing Word / Excel files (not PDF - for which I can use `<embed />` tag).

Thanks

Comment: I think you are right - they work with publicly available docs, only. I am also interested in alternative solution, for intranet/localhost files, but was unable to find one, so far ...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to install Office Web Apps Server locally.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/webappsserver/office-web-apps-server-overview

Office Web Apps Server provides a page at the address http://OfficeWebAppsServername/op/generate.aspx that you can use to generate links to publicly available documents that have UNC or URL addresses. When a user selects a generated URL, Online Viewers enable Office Web Apps Server to get the file from its location and then render it by using Office Web Apps. The user can view the Word, Excel, or PowerPoint file in a browser with Office features intact. Formatting and layout in Word documents are preserved, data in Excel workbooks can be filtered and sorted, and animations play in PowerPoint presentations. However, be aware that Online Viewers allow users to view but not edit files, and Online Viewers can't open any files that require authentication.